# Do macroscopic bodies also show quantum nature at extremely low temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons

If we consider atoms or molecules and cool them to extremely low tempertures, will they also show quantum nature. Will their wave nature also get dominated? And if they are bosons, will they become a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Comment: Superconductor?

Comment: It sounds like you have some ideas as to why that may be true, so you should add those ideas to your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two scenarios, where it happens :
Superfluidity & Superconductivity

As the wikipedia article says,

> Superfluidity : At temperatures below the lambda point, helium shows the unique property of superfluidity. The fraction of the liquid that forms the superfluid component is a macroscopic quantum fluid.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_quantum_phenomena

Answer (score 0):

A macroscopic mechanical resonator having a high frequency $\omega$ can display quantum properties at low temperature T (say, if $\hbar\omega>kT$) (https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-effect-spotted-in-a-visible-object/)